# A function that create function with string manipulation

Tags: macros, expansion, xstring

I suppose this is just a simple question, but I am stucked.

I need for a translation work the possibility to create something like this:

```
\newcommand\dog{cane}
\newcommand\Dog{Cane}
```

Instead of creating two function, I'm asking myself if it's possible to create something like

```
\aCustomFunction{dog}{cane}
\begin{document}
    \dog

    \Dog
\end{document}
```

That compile for me the uppercase version and the lowercase version of the string.

the `xstring` packgage give me `\StrLeft` and `\StrGobbleLeft` to take the first letter and the command `\uppercase{}` can be useful too. But if I try to define a function, I get losted on expansion with `\expandafter`:

```
%This is the uppercase string manipulation: dog -> Dog (or cane -> Cane)
\newcommand\FirstLetterUppercase[1]{\uppercase{\StrLeft{#1}{1}}\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}}
%This is the double define function
\newcommand\newUpperCommand[2]{%
  %This is the lowercase function: \newcommand\dog{cane}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
  %This is the uppercase function: \newcommand\Dog{Cane}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname\FirstLetterUppercase{#1}\endcsname{\FirstLetterUppercase{#2}}%
}
```

This way is, of course, incorrect. Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach with `stringstrings`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand\aCustomFunction[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
  \capitalizewords[q]{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname\thestring\endcsname{\capitalizewords{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
\aCustomFunction{dog}{cane}

\dog

\Dog
\end{document}
```

[image]

As it is, the above approach reinvokes `\capitalizewords` for every instance of `\Dog`.  That can be avoided in the following way, so that `\Dog` literally contains the string "Cane":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand\aCustomFunction[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
  \capitalizewords[q]{#1}%
  \edef\tmp{\thestring}%
  \capitalizewords[q]{#2}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\tmp\endcsname{\thestring}%
}
\begin{document}
\aCustomFunction{dog}{cane}

\dog

\Dog
\end{document}
```

Note that either of the approaches will allow indirect syntax such as

```
\def\blah{this is a test}
\aCustomFunction{cat}{\blah}

\cat

\Cat
```

[image]

However, only the original approach will keep track of things if `\blah` is redefined mid-stream.

Comment: For me this is an excellent solution.Even if I don't understand why `stringstring` package doesn't need expansion. Thank you!

Comment: @AlbertoVerdoja see my supplemental comments on how to improve the efficiency of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CustomFunction}{mom}
 {% #1 = command name, #2 = optional initial, #3 = string
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \verdoja_custom_function:ffff
     { \tl_head:n {#1} } { \tl_tail:n {#1} }
     { \tl_head:n {#3} } { \tl_tail:n {#3} }
   }
   {
    \verdoja_custom_function:ffnn 
     { \tl_head:n {#1} } { \tl_tail:n {#1} }
     { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \verdoja_custom_function:nnnn
 {
  \tl_new:c { #1 #2 }
  \tl_set:cn { #1 #2 }{ #3 #4 }
  \tl_new:c { \text_uppercase:n { #1 } #2 }
  \tl_set:cx { \text_uppercase:n { #1 } #2 } { \text_uppercase:n { #3 } #4 }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \verdoja_custom_function:nnnn { ff , ffff }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\CustomFunction{dog}{cane}
\CustomFunction{elite}[é]{lite}

\begin{document}

\dog

\Dog

\elite

\Elite

\end{document}
```

If the first character is special, it's necessary to use the optional character (for compatibility with `pdflatex`, in case XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is used the optional argument is not required).

[image]

Actually, with the recent additions and refinements to `expl3`, we can vastly simplify the code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CustomFunction}{mm}
 {% #1 = command name, #2 = string
  \verdoja_custom_function:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \verdoja_custom_function:nn
 {
  \tl_const:cn { #1 } { #2 }
  \tl_const:cx { \char_titlecase:N #1 } { \text_titlecase:n { #2 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\CustomFunction{dog}{cane}
\CustomFunction{elite}{élite}

\begin{document}

\dog

\Dog

\elite

\Elite

\end{document}
```

We no longer need the initial to be in an optional argument if “special".